# I am unable to run my react native app on my iOS device or android studio emulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, expo, expo-go

Today I opened my app and tried to fire it up using the Expo app on my iOS device and received the following error in the phone app:

*There was a problem loading the requested app.

Could not connect to the server / The request timed out.
It looks like you may be using LAN URI. Make sure your device is on the same network as the server, and that you have granted Expo Go the Local Network permission in the Settings app, or try using the tunnel connection type.*

I then tried to run it through the android studio emulator but received another error:

```
The app might not be installed, try installing it with: npx expo run:android -d Medium_Phone_API_29
Activity class {exp://192.168.0.16:8081:8081} does not exist.
```

When I run the recommended command I get another error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in you
```

I have already tried to find answers to this but nothing has worked. The strangest thing is that yesterday everything worked fine and today when I tried to run it these errors appeared.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set on your system, and the system cannot locate the Java executable in your PATH.
you can resolve this issue by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the guide below:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?os=macos#installing-dependencies